# Can't retrieve client.guilds.cache in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I have a bot where I want to set it's activity to `PLAYING X Servers` EX: `PLAYING 300 Servers`
So I wrote this in my ready.js event file

`` client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache} Servers | re!help`, { type: "PLAYING" }); ``

but just got this `[object Map] Servers | re!help` in the status of the bot, I have no Idea what's that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `client.guilds.cache` is a `Collection`, which is basically just an extension of a JS `Map`. If you want to get the *size* of that collection, you're going to want to do `client.guilds.cache.size`. So your line of code should be:

```
client.user.setActivity(`${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers | re!help`, { type: "PLAYING" });
```

Comment: Thank you very much <3

Comment: @KarimWalid Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, please mark this as the solution :)

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna do it but stackoverflow doesn't let you mark an answer as a solution unless it passes 9 minutes.